Minimum APIs for Android Application to receive FCM notifications
At my company we are trying to restrict our Google API keys (the ones Firebase creates for you) to the minimum required to handle our FCM notifications.  We only use direct to device notifications, no topics of any kind.  In small scale test this seems to only have required the Firebase Installations API.
This allows us to retrieve a token for the device from the API Call:
val firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance()

firebaseMessaging.token

This token alone lets us send a FCM notification from our server-side solution.
The imports in our Android app are:
com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging
com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage
com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService

with a dependency on:
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.2

Is there anything I am missing here or other APIs that we should be including?  Any help would be appreciated.  I am limited to how much source code I can share.

Your question isn't clear (at least to me). What you mean by restrict?

@user27894462 We are following the principals of least privilege.  When you create you application in FCM, it is created with a lot of Google's available APIs.  Most of which you may not need.  You can restrict the API key that google creates for you to reduce the amount of APIs it has access to.
